# MySQL: Should this set of custom member records form a separate DB, a new table, or just new columns?

Tags: mysql, content-management-system, merge, forum

I have two MySQL databases,one from a membership script (MS) and one from a forum script (FS).

MS is like this:

```
___________________________________________________  

useremail    |      membergroups | oranges | apples | pears |... (and 30 more columns)  
_______________________________________________  
jill@jill.com | A,B,C     | 1     |  0  |   1  |...... (and 30 more values)
________________________________________________  


and FS is like this:


- - - - -- - - - -- - - -- - - - - -- - - -

USER_ID  | USERNAME | EMAIL     |    GROUPTYPE  |
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -- - - -
2289   | jill     | jill@jill.com | gold  |
---------------------------------------------
```

So:

1) The two member tables are of course very different.
2) The MS member table has many, many data columns.

Goals:
1) I'd like to draw on the many data in MS in whatever membership script/forum combo I wind up ultimately using.
2) I want to establish a Single Sign-On, so the user only needs to login once for both systems to operate.

Question:
Would it be best to

a) store the MS data in the existing MS DB, and just have the FS DB query it;
b) add a new table to the FS DB, and add the old MS data to the new FS table, so that
are now two distinct tables carrying member data in the same DB;
c) add the MS data to newly created columns in the FS DB;
d) do something else that I haven't thought of.

My gut says "b" is the best choice, but since I've gotta hire someone to do this, I'll stackoverflow's insights over the promptings of my gut.

Answer (score 0):

In my respect `b` is also best choice. I prefer you to go with it .

Comment: Thanks!  If MS uses USEREMAIL and FS uses USER_ID#, is it best to create some *new* key, like USERSPECIAL_ID, for the new table?   Basically, does the new table need a new key for the members, or if not, should it use the key from MS or FS?

Comment: it is always better to keep one primary key id in each table , which will be unique , and it is better to define relation by assigning the foreign keys , In your ms table there is not primary key (means id ), so add one id in this table and if do you want to have relation betweent ms and fs ?

Comment: Thanks again! >>and if do you want to have relation betweent ms and fs?<<  Just to be clear, when I add the new SPECIAL_ID# in the new FS table holding the old MS data, do I also add that as a data field in the old FS table? If I have an external PHP function that uses the old MS data which has now been placed in a new FS table,does it have to go through the FS system (and require a relationship between the FS and MS member tables), or can I just have the PHP code reference the new table directly? (Thanks for your suggestions! :)